# How to pass the Stripe token to the charge object without creating a PaymentSource?

Tags: java, stripe-payments

It seems like there are two ways to create a Stripe Charge:

1) Using a map of properties, where the Stripe token is just another String property:

```
Map<String, Object> chargeParams = new HashMap<String, Object>();
chargeParams.put("amount", 400);
chargeParams.put("currency", "usd");
chargeParams.put("source", "tok_15jGykA1uVHZiLuVZf6lmzyd"); 
chargeParams.put("description", "some desc");
Charge.create(chargeParams);
```

2) Setting params directly on the Charge object:

```
Charge charge = new Charge();
charge.setAmount(400);
charge.setCurrency("USD");
charge.setDescription("some desc");
charge.setSource("tok_15jGykA1uVHZiLuVZf6lmzyd");  // doesn't work!
```

I'd prefer using option 2, but it doesn't seem like I can. It seems silly that I can't pass the String token to the Charge object directly. It wants me to create a PaymentSource, and pass that to setSource(). But I don't have the PaymentSource. Just the token.

Has anyone done this successfully?

Comment: I don't think that's possible since `PaymentSource` doesn't expect a `token`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the Stripes team, this is not supported. They chose to have the Java library accept parameter maps so that developers don't have to upgrade to the newest version of Stripes every time they make a non backwards compatible change. Fair enough.